# Angular reactive forms check existing number

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a table in my angular application where I store some data (users, email, etc.), I can add new users and in my form there is an input field where I can type in an importance number (1 , 2 , 3 and so on) and of course there should be only one of each number. I want to show an error message if the typed number already exists in my database. Is there a way to use a validator to check it?

Comment: You mean like [async validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#creating-asynchronous-validators)?

Comment: Use async validator https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidator. If any problem then share your code

Comment: that's what I was looking for thanks, I will try it

Answer (score 1):

You should add a custom async validator.

The following code create the validator class, CheckIfNumberExistsValidator, which implements the AsyncValidator interface.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CheckIfNumberExistsValidator implements AsyncValidator {
  constructor(private numbersService: NumbersService) {}

  validate(
    ctrl: AbstractControl
  ): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return this.numbersService.isNumberTaken(ctrl.value).pipe(
      map(isTaken => (isTaken ? { uniqueNumber: true } : null)),
      catchError(() => of(null))
    );
  }
}
```

Your form should look like:

```
this.yourForm = new FormGroup({
  number: new FormControl(0, {
        asyncValidators: [this.CheckIfNumberExistsValidator.validate.bind(this.CheckIfNumberExistsValidator )],
        updateOn: 'blur' // You can delay updating the form validity
      }),
});
```

The **NumbersService** would be responsible for making an HTTP request to the numbers database.

This method returns null if the form is valid, and ValidationErrors if it is not.

Note: Don't forget to inject **CheckIfNumberExistsValidator**

For more info, check: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#implementing-a-custom-async-validator